# Controll of MATLAB dll from C++ code

Tags: c++, matlab

I run from C++ a MATLAB function (dll). This function gets some parameters and
runs a loop with many itterations. Is there is a way to set some flag in C++ code and check it on each itteration from MATLAB function. If this flag is set to false (let say by an other thread ) in C++ code MATLAB function will break the loop and return to C++ code

Comment: How about if in case of flag event you create a file and MATLAB check for it with `exist` function?

Comment: Do you have the source of the dll?

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify both C++ and MATLAB codes (as we can assume from the question) I think the easiest way would be to use an empty file as the flag of an event. If some other thread can create a file, let's say 'event.flag', you can easily check its existence in MATLAB function:

```
if exist('event.flag','file')
    % do_something
end
```

Make sure to include the second argument `file`, that will make exist run much faster.

I believe this solution is much easy and error-proof than trying to use any global variables.

---

If you need to exchange some data between MATLAB and other process in run time I'd recommend to use [MEMMAPFILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memmapfile.html) object. Check the documentation to see if it will be appropriate in your case.